# TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer. Received an instance of Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, chai

```
let chai = require('chai');
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
let app = require('../routes/post');
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('/POST Post', () => {
    it('Post status successfully' ,(done)=> {
        chai.request(app).post("/")
        .send({userName:"Sameena" , status:"Hi,this is Sameena test"})
        .end((res) => {
          res.should.have.status(201);
          res.body.should.be.a('object');
          done();
        }).catch(done);
    });
});
```

Warning: superagent request was sent twice, because both .end() and .then() were called. Never call .end() if you use promises
Warning: .end() was called twice. This is not supported in superagent

I tried changing the .end to .then and .send but I get done() not given error.